# Приходилось ли вам создавать многомерные массивы?

Tags: любой-язык

Например, 16-мерные массивы итп. Где это вообще может использоваться?

Comment: Может использоваться для расчета движения в 16-мерном пространстве.

Comment: Не с той стороны подходите. Вы взяли структуру данных - многомерный массив - и стали думать: куда бы её приткнуть? Нужно наоборот: взять конкретную задачу и думать, как её решить, с помощью каких структур данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тензор](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) - математическая сущность изображения. Многомерные массивы актуальны для решения задач компьютерного зрения и нейросетей. Например, любое изображение можно представить как массив массивов с тремя элементами (R,G,B). Относительно нейросетей, характерным примером является название фреймворка обучения от Google, [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).

Comment: RGB это все же массив из трех элементов, а не трехмерный массив.

Comment: @freim верно, спасибо!